# Log duplication with asynchronous event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, browser, throttling

I have a simple React snippet which produces surprising console output in the browser:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isFetching) return;
    setIsFetching(true);
    console.log("fetch 1");
    console.log("fetch 2");

    try {
      const response = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }, 10);
      });
      setData((prev) => [...prev, response]);
    } finally {
      setIsFetching(false);
      console.log(`done 1`);
      console.log(`done 2`);
    }
  }, [setData, isFetching]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", fetchData);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", fetchData);
    };
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setData([]);
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </button>
      <h1 className="Data">Data: {data}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/scroll-callback-state-tryawaitref-working-forked-37k8xs?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A13%2C25&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0006356he2066tdd%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70.4225377538944%252C29.577462246105597%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0002356hcmmp3d7b%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0003356h1dzss2fr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0005356hjap8gd0q%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B51.98652521494293%252C48.01347478505707%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clszl09uv0002356hcmmp3d7b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0002356hcmmp3d7b%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clszmphfe0002356h4jzu6hwz%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszliltv008q356hueygit4g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszmphfe0002356h4jzu6hwz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A25%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A13%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A25%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clszl09uv0005356hjap8gd0q%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0005356hjap8gd0q%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszmty2u00kx356hciju25o2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clszmty2u00kx356hciju25o2%2522%257D%252C%2522clszl09uv0003356h1dzss2fr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszl09uv0003356h1dzss2fr%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt10mhor0055356h14l78tld%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszlhs3j002s356hpaoi038b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt10mhor0055356h14l78tld%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt10mqr70019dheiegy87rfb%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

When scrolling there is an uneven ratio of adjacent `console.log` prints, where you may see:

- fetch 1
- fetch 2
- fetch 2
- done 1
- done 2

or some combination where 5 or more statements appear to make up one function call.

While React itself is not desynchronized, the strange output caused me to worry about lifecycle bugs in a complex project. Not to mention clouding the logs so much that they lost readability.

Note:

- Refs do not help
- Throttling/debouncing does not help